# Laravel Eloquent: In many to many relationships the ORM is returning only one Object

Tags: php, orm, laravel-4, many-to-many, eloquent

My table structure is like:
  skills
     -id
     - name

openings
 -id
 ....

openings_skills
   -id
   -opening_id
   -skill_id

These are my two models.

```
class Skill extends Eloquent {
protected $table = 'skills';
public function opening() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Opening', 'openings_skills');
}
}


class Opening extends Eloquent  {
protected $table = 'openings';  
public function skill() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Skill', 'openings_skills');
}
}
```

When I try to retrieve the data using the below code, I only get single object in the collection so iterating over it gives me a skill name.

```
    $opening = Opening::find($id);
    foreach($opening->skill as $skill){
        echo $skill;
    }
```

How could I extract all the skills for that particular opening using the pivoted table 'openings_skills' ?
P.S: I'm using Laravel 4.9.11 version for my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried this myself, and here's the working code i used:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSkillsTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('skills', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('skills');
}

}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOpeningsTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('openings', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('opening');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('openings');
}

}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOpeningsSkillsTable extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('openings_skills', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('skill_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('opening_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('skill_id')->references('id')->on('skills')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('opening_id')->references('id')->on('openings')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('openings_skills');
}

}
```

// and here's the route i used.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
   $opening = Opening::find(1);
   dd($opening->skill);
});
```

i also used the same models that you provided. so i think your problem might be in how you created the migrations.
let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the whether the foreign key values are correct values in your join tables?